# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop when using useState()

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Login from "./Login";

function App() {

  const [id, setId] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      {id}
      <Login onSubmit={setId()}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and

Login.js:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { Container, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Login({ onIdSubmit }) {

    const idRef = useRef();

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        onIdSubmit(idRef.current.value)
    }

    return (
        <Container className="align-items-center d-flex" style={{height: "100vh"}}>
            <Form  className="w-100" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Enter your Id
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" ref={idRef} required/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Button type="submit" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginTop: "5px"}}>Login</Button>
                <Button variant="secondary" style={{marginTop: "5px"}}>Create A New Id</Button>
            </Form>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

It appears that the error is in the App.js on the `onSubmit={setId()}` because when I comment it out it works.

The idea here is that when you click the "Login" button the value in the `<Form.Control type="text" ref={idRef} required/>` is stored in the useState from the App.js. Can I do this without getting the `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`?

Comment: `<Login onSubmit={setId} />`, just pass the function, don't call it

Comment: also the name of prop in login component is `onIdSubmit`, while you are passing the  prop `onSubmit` to Login in your App component. Make sure you use the same prop name at both the places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use setId without parenthesis `()`. When you write the parenthesis beside a function, it means you are actually calling the function, which is causing rerenders. But in your case, you just want to pass the reference of your function to your Child Component.

```
<Login onIdSubmit={setId}/>
```

And also rename onSubmit to `onIdSubmit` as @Vaibhav commented.